# Which these php script use less memory of server?

Tags: php

```
function test($matches)
{
    $fx = '';
    if(strpos($matches[0],"http://")===false)
    {
        $fx = "http://";
    }
    elseif(strpos($matches[0],"http:/")===false)
    {
        $fx = "http:/";
    }
    elseif(strpos($matches[0],"http:")===false)
    {
        $fx = "http:";
    }
    elseif(strpos($matches[0],"http")===false)
    {
        $fx = "http";
    }
    return $fx.$matches[0];
}
```

or

```
function test($matches)
{
    if(strpos($matches[0],"http://")===false)
    {
        return  "http://".$matches[0];
    }
    elseif(strpos($matches[0],"http:/")===false)
    {
        return "http:/".$matches[0];
    }
    elseif(strpos($matches[0],"http:")===false)
    {
        return "http:".$matches[0];
    }
    elseif(strpos($matches[0],"http")===false)
    {
        return "http".$matches[0];
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write my scripts to them use less memory as possible, but idk sometimes the code look ugly, in my opnion the first script look more pretty and organized, but i think it use more memory of server.

thanks.

Comment: Benchmark them with [`memory_get_usage()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) and [`memory_get_peak_usage()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php).

Comment: However, you really shouldn't worry about it unless your server is giving poor performance or cannot meet the demands on it.  The difference between these two (if there is any) will be so immeasurably negligible.

Comment: These function return two different things. The first always returns a result while the second does not. While you are at it test a switch case function too.

Comment: Well, i got alot of domain on same ip, then i'm a bit worry about it and trying to write all script to use less memory as possible, well anyway should i care about it?

Comment: @Michael i agree, IMHO maintainability is 100x more important than memory usage, esp for small snippets like this.  programmer time is expensive, ram is cheap.  if you're really concerned about performance, switch to a faster language.

Comment: Probably the second one uses slightly less memory since it doesn't need to store a variable first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as which one will use less memory, I would think they are equivalent (both at their worst case).

However, as for their run times, the second one will finish executing a fraction of a nano-second faster than the first because, it will return as soon as it finds one matching condition. Over all the difference in Big-O is constant which we all know doesn't make a difference: O(3n) verses O(n) at the best case, and O(3n) verse O(3n) at worst case (dependant on the size of $match[0]). **But all this is deeply dependant on the complexity of the strpos() function**.

For readability, they are also equilavently written and structured.

Comment: did u know where i can find tips to write my scripts to use less memory?